# Parse Server throws "Failed to create instance of subclass." if Data Store is enabled

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to instantiate a subclass on Parse Server and do some **query.find()**, everyting was working fine until I enabled the "Local Data Store".

After I add **.enableLocalDataStore()** to Parse.initialize(), the **query.find()** throws the following exception:

**"java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create instance of subclass."**

Looks like the **.enableLocalDataStore()** is blocking the register of subclasses. This is very weird since one thing has nothing to do with another.

```
public class App extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Place.class); // registering the subclass
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                        .applicationId("...")
                        .server("...")
                        .enableLocalDataStore() // if I remove this line, it works!
                        .build()
        );
    }
}
```

If I remove the line **".enableLocalDataStore()"**, it works fine. Coul'd this be some incompatibility?

This is happening with other people too. See the GitHub page for this issue:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/issues/379

So far, no good awnsers

Answer (score 0):

I answered on the GitHub page, but I 'll also answer here :

If you have

```
public String getObjectId() {
    return getString(objectId);
}
```

in your subclass, just **delete it**. It's useless and it breaks everything.